# How to remove a point from a closed vector shape in Illustrator without breaking the shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

When I try to delete a node in a space, by pressing DEL, the closed-shape it gets broken (not-continous anymore).

How can I remove point from these without breaking them?

Note: I used Illustrator CS6, is this makes a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the pen tool in the menu bar there is a tool called delete anchor points. You can also access this with the shortcut key <kbd>-</kbd> (minus). It allows you to remove anchor points without breaking the shape
[image]